# Aligning Image Slideshow button HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, list, css

So I have trouble arranging my images to line up next to one another horizontally. They are actually slideshows which I modified so that they act as buttons instead. I used easyslider javascript to perform the function, not sure if easyslider might be the cause. So the thing is that they line themselves down vertically. I tried adding "float : left" to a css id element and attach it to the images however to no avail.

```
 <div id="sliderparent">

            <div class="slider">
        <ul>                
            <li>
                <a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-1.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li>
                    <a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-2.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li>
                        <a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-3.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li>
                            <a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-4.jpg" /></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
#sliderparent {
width: 800px;
align-content:center;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
.slider ul, .slider li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
      position:initial;

    }
.slider li{ 
    /* 
        define width and height of list item (slide)
        entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
    */ 
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden; 
     float:left;
    }       
.sliderimg
 { 
    width:200px; 
      height: auto; 
      float:left;
}
```

I am not sure if it is due to my list arrangement.

Can someone shed some light on the cause as to why my images aren't aligning the way I want them to?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a problem. Your code works. I made some slight adjustments below to demonstrate it working. Are you having issues with a particular browser?

http://jsfiddle.net/rkT2k/

```
<div id="sliderparent">
    <div class="slider">
    <ul>                
        <li><a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-2.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-3.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#article1"><img class="sliderimg"src="images/example-slide-4.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#sliderparent {
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
.slider ul,
.slider li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: initial;
 }
.slider li {
    /* define width and height of list item (slide)
       entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here */ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    float: left;
}       
.sliderimg { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: auto; 
    float: left;

    /* make images blocks temporarily */
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think I wasn't clear with the codes. There are supposed to be 2 slideshow objects not just one. And I want to align them side by side as the width is 800px and each button is only 200px so I should be able to fit 4 buttons into the sliderparent before it goes down to a new row.

Comment: @user2330725 Can you explain this further? Update your question so what you're trying to accomplish is clear. You want to have two `ul`s with 4 buttons/images each? And all of this should be in the same row?